# What is the OLEDB destination table name?

Tags: vb.net, ssis, oledb

Please see the code in the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136020.aspx

It involves adding a dataflow, which contains an OLEDB data source and OLEDB destination.  How do I specify the table name of the OLEDB destination? I cannot see where SetComponentProperty is called on the OLEDB destination object.

Comment: Looks like an omission on the site.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to set the OLEDB destination table name in VB.net

```
destDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 3)
destDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", "Production.Product")
```

This is the C# version.

```
destDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 3);
destDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", "Production.Product");
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Here is some documentation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/api-sample-oledb-source-and-oledb-destination.aspx